# SSV/CSV Manipulation: Calculate Ratios

Tags: bash, awk, csv, datamash

Note that I am aware of `datamash` and an experienced `awk` user. I am looking for something a bit simpler/streamlined than `awk`. Suppose I have the following:

```
// data_file
foo bar biz
10  100 1000
11  150 990
10  95  1010
9   99  950
```

```
// usage goal, in pseudo code
cat data_file | <tool> --ratio foo,bar --ratio foo,biz --ratio bar,biz
```

```
// desired output
foo bar biz foo_bar foo_biz bar_biz
10  100 1000 0.1    0.01    0.1  
11  150 990  0.073  0.011   0.1515
10  95  1010 0.105  0.0099  0.094
9   99  950  0.09   0.0095  0.1042
```

In order to get this interface, I'll build something trivial in c++.

Before doing that, is there a drop-in solution for this in Unix?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. Do you require the command line parameters of `<tool>` to accept any number of column name pairs referring to string values that must appear in the first row of your data file? Do you want to be able to specify any number of pairs in any order?

Comment: @Bodo yes, I would like to be able to have a text file containing a row of inputs to be used in an expression as follows:  `cat data_file | <tool> \`cat ratios\``. This is embedded in a makefile routine (hence syntactical cleanliness is a priority; janky awk calls and scripts will make the makefile difficult to read).

Comment: **Please [edit] your question** to add information. **Don't answer requests for clarification in comments.** Please describe the format of the file `ratios` and why it is defined this way? Is the file `ratios` generated somehow? How is the input file generated? Is the ordering and naming of columns in the input data fixed? Why not generate an `awk` script instead of your `ratios` file? Is the line `// data_file` part of the file as your formatting suggests?

Comment: what's the input file field separator?

Comment: @aborruso space. I formatted for readability.

Comment: @aborruso this is indicated in the question title: "SSV/CSV"

Comment: @donlan I had never read before SSV. Now I know that it's Space Separated Values :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a couple of bash functions, `paste`, `bc` and `csvtool` you can get there pretty straightforwardly if you have a file to work with:

```
div() {
  printf "%1.4f\n" $(bc -l <<<"1.0 * $1 / $2")
}
export -f div

ratio() {
  echo "$1"_"$2"
  csvtool -t ' ' namedcol $1,$2 data.ssv |
  tail -n+2                              |
  csvtool call div -
}

paste -d ' ' <(cat data.ssv) <(ratio foo bar) <(ratio foo biz) <(ratio bar biz) |
csvtool -t ' ' readable -
```

Output:

```
foo bar biz  foo_bar foo_biz bar_biz 
10  100 1000 0.1000  0.0100  0.1000  
11  150 990  0.0733  0.0111  0.1515  
10  95  1010 0.1053  0.0099  0.0941  
9   99  950  0.0909  0.0095  0.1042
```

If you really want to do it in a streaming fashion, your best option is probably `awk`, e.g.:

*parse.awk*

```c
# Parse the requested column ratios into dividend[] and divisor[]
# by column name
BEGIN {
  split(ratios_str, ratios, / +/)
  for(r in ratios) {
    split(ratios[r], cols, /,/)
    dividend[++i] = cols[1] 
    divisor[i]    = cols[2]
  }
}

# Sort out the header
NR == 1 { 
  # Create the ColumnName-to-ColumnNumber hash
  split($0, a); for(k in a) c2n[a[k]]=k

  # Print the header line
  printf "%s ", $0
  for(i=1; i<=length(dividend); i++)
    printf "%s_%s ", dividend[i], divisor[i]
  printf "\n"
}

NR > 1 {
  printf "%s ", $0
  for(i=1; i<=length(dividend); i++)
    printf "%1.4f ", $(c2n[dividend[i]]) / $(c2n[divisor[i]])
  printf "\n"
}
```

Run it like this:

```
<data.ssv awk -f parse.awk -v ratios_str='foo,bar foo,biz bar,biz' | column -t
```

Output:

```
foo  bar  biz   foo_bar  foo_biz  bar_biz
10   100  1000  0.1000   0.0100   0.1000
11   150  990   0.0733   0.0111   0.1515
10   95   1010  0.1053   0.0099   0.0941
9    99   950   0.0909   0.0095   0.1042
```

Answer (score 3):

Using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) and run

```
mlr --pprint put '$foo_bar=$foo/$bar;$foo_biz=$foo/$biz;$bar_biz=$bar/$biz' input >output
```

you have

```
foo bar biz  foo_bar  foo_biz  bar_biz
10  100 1000 0.100000 0.010000 0.100000
11  150 990  0.073333 0.011111 0.151515
10  95  1010 0.105263 0.009901 0.094059
9   99  950  0.090909 0.009474 0.104211
```